# How to get validation errors like field and rule key with Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter-4

I am developing a project using CodeIgniter 4. I handle CRUD operations using model-based validation. In Create or Update operations, if a validation error occurs, I can retrieve the error messages with

```
$model->errors()
```

but these error messages come with language translation. For a different purpose, I want to retrieve the error messages in the format

```
["field" => "rule"]
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried methods like listErrors and getErrors, but they did not give me the desired result.

Comment: Share exactly what you're currently receiving and what you expect. Otherwise,  your question is unclear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example